# When network type change wifi to 3g, web service connection timeout

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

Dearl ALL,

I created one xamarin app.It using web service. Every connection is ok if use only wifi or 3g. But time out error come out when switching wifi to 3G OR 3G to wifi.

A list of steps to is as follows:

1.) Start the application on a phone using wifi.

2.) Attempt to retrieve data. The result is successful retrieval.

3.) Using the quick settings bar (pulling down from top of screen), turn wifi off so you're on 3G data.

4.) Attempt to retrieve data again and can't retrieve. The error message is 
    "The operation has timeout".  Try again in 1 or 2 minutes, result is the 
     same.

5.) After attempting to retrieve data and receiving a failure on the first attempt, try again and can't succeed.

I'm using Channel Model for web service. Below is sample

```
   nMobileSoapClient client = new nMobileSoapClient(
               new BasicHttpBinding(),
               new EndpointAddress("Web Service URL"));
            client.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
            client.InnerChannel.Open();
```

public nMobileSoapClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

Same issue in IOS applicaiton.

Please, help me for this issue.

Comment: you have to share some code, related parts.

Comment: you need to edit the question add the codes related to the issue, so other people can solve/guide you through this. **i am using android to call service** is not accurate and not helpful

Comment: if i want to answer the above question, with the provided details, my answer will be: use a `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: You need to check network is connected.Then do any api calls ..

    ex if(Isconnecged){
    Do whatever 
    }

*Or if connectivity is chaged to any other medium(ex wifi,Mobile data) just implement brodcaset receiver to callback event and  cancel the current api call and retry the call using any quque service*

Answer (score 0):

When you swicth the connection, the mobilesoapclient need to be completely reintialised for it to work. So, you would need to catch any network errors, and then reinitialise the soapclient and then try again.

Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. @Libin Joseph.
 
Could you share any link or sample how to reintialised the mobilesoapclient?